# I don't know why occurred this? "java.nio.channels.UnresolvedAddressException"

Tags: java, firebase, netty, solaris, firebase-cloud-messaging

I made program having a function to send the message to FCM server using Netty.

and I finished the tested in Windows 7.

it works well.

but solaris does not run this.

I got a exception code in solaris.

```
[ClientHandler.exceptionCaught] Unexpected exception from downstream.java.nio.channels.UnresolvedAddressException
```

this exception error is occurred after

> "[ClientHandler.channelOpen]"

and then run to

> "[ClientHandler.channelClosed]"

so, I did try write message to FCM Server after Immediately "[ClientHandler.channelOpen]".

message sent from FCM Server.

and got a another exception error .

```
"java.nio.channels.NotYetConnectedException"
```

that is knows that an error occurs in the above problem.

I don't know why occurred "UnresolvedAddressException".

I think that this problem occurs because the Solaris firewall.

how to handle this issue?

Add to..
Ping test results

```
ping 64.233.187.188
64.233.187.188 is alive
```

Note - this IP is gained by using the

```
String ip = "fcm-xmpp.googleapis.com";
int port = 5236;
new InetSocketAddress (ip, port) .getAddress () getHostAddress ()
```

in java.

Comment: Can you use the linux CLI to run `dig addressYouAreGoing.to`?

Comment: hi,  yes i can do . and then what should I do?

Comment: Does it show that the address is resolving? If not maybe your OS doesn't have the right DNS server.

Comment: i found "resolv.conf". the contents of the file is / 
nameserver 168.126.63.1 /
do i have to additional to other task?

Comment: There was a mistake. OS is Solaris.

Comment: You're pinging the IP address - `ping 64.233.187.188` then trying a TCP connect to `fcm-xmpp.googleapis.com:5236`.  That's like testing if a paper airplane can fly by bouncing a tennis ball off the floor and measuring how high it bounces.  Try testing the TCP connectivity with *TCP connectivity*:  `telnet fcm-xmpp.googleapis.com 5236`.

Comment: Hi
Previously it was proceeding as following order.
1. nslookup fcm-xmpp.googleapis.com
    - Name:   gcm.l.google.com    Address: 64.233.187.188
2. ping 64.233.189.188
    - 64.233.189.188 is alive
3. traceroute 64.233.189.188
    - 64.233.189.188 (64.233.189.188)  63.248 ms  62.285 ms  63.013 ms

If the above contents is normal, Linux can be a problem? or Is the problem in code?

Comment: What version of Solaris ?

Comment: Solaris version is  10 8/07 s10s_u4wos_12b SPARC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll improve on this answer as we move along.

You seem to have a misconfigured Solaris system. Misconfigured in terms of host name lookup.

1. Let us know your version of Solaris. Do `cat /etc/release` and 
   post the output.
2. On Solaris there's a beast called *Solaris Name Service daemon*
   which caches name information. Other OS'es have a similar concept.
   All relevant system calls in Solaris asks this daemon for name
   information, however the `nslookup` tool bypasses this and asks
   directly from a DNS server. This is why you can have a successful
   `nslookup`, while name lookup in general do not work. Bottom line:
   `nslookup` is sometimes not the test you want to do. Use `getent`
   command instead, as in `getent hosts fcm-xmpp.googleapis.com`.
3. Andrew Henley's comment is spot on. You should execute the `telnet` test.
   It gives valuable information. This is a well-known method for testing
   connectivity and it should be part of any IT person's toolbox whether 
   you are a developer or a sysadmin, IMHO. (Windows people normally do
   not know about the 'telnet test' mainly because Microsoft has decided
   that the [telnet client should no longer be installed by default on 
   Windows](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771275(v=ws.10).aspx))

Comment: Thank you for answer.
I check "telnet" and there was no firewall problems.
Maybe it can on code problems.


If i work test in different OS(window, solaris), each results may varied?

Comment: i found a way.

It was a matter of Java code.

InetSocketAddress did not recognize the host information.
so Calling getAddress it returns null.

so i changed the host information. 
host = "fcm-xmpp.googleapis.com" >>> host = "64.233.187.188"
InetSocketAddress  occasionally think does not recognize the host information.

Comment: Yes, your Java problem is that `new InetSocketAddress("fcm-xmpp.googleapis.com", port)` returns an unresolved object, but that is the *symptom*. The *cause* is that there's some problem with host name resolution on this particular Solaris host. You use the word "occasionally" about the problem so I'm assuming that host name resolution on that host only occasionally works. Long term you should fix that problem. Short term you can do as you've did.